# golang; trouble understanding a function as a receiver

Tags: go

I'm trying to read through this: https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go specifically the section titled `Simplifying repetitive error handling`.

They call `http.Handle` like this:

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/view", appHandler(viewRecord))
}
```

`http.Handle`'s second argument expects a type `Handler` (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) which needs to have a method `serveHttp`.

The `serveHttp` function here:

```
func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    }
}
```

So, their type `appHandler` now implements the Handler interface because it implements `ServeHTTP`, I got that. So it can be used in the `Handle` function whereas `viewRecord` cannot.

Where I'm getting confused is between the relationship between `viewRecord` which is of type `appHandler` and `ServeHTTP`. Which calls which? They  make a parenthetical comment about how "a function can be a receiver too" and I think that's where I'm getting tripped up.

Here, with `fn appHandler` as the receiver, I would expect something like `viewRecord.serveHTTP()`, but that doesn't make sense, and `viewRecord` is a function. What I think is happening is that the `Handle` function calls `serveHTTP`, but how does `serveHTTP` call `viewRecord`?

UPDATE/SELF ANSWER:

What was missing from the above question which is critical to understanding was

1. the defn of `appHandler` : `type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error`
2. the fact that `appHandler` *implements the same interface as* `viewRecord`, which is the `Handle` interface, therefore `viewRecord` can be *cast* to an `appHandler`. That is a cast, not a function call!
3. `ServeHTTP` invokes `viewRecord` (appHandler) inside the implementation of `ServeHTTP` using the `fn` reciever

Comment: For newcomers: There are **2 prerequisites** to understanding what's going on here. **1)** Read the 'Simplifying repetitive error handling' section in [OP's first link](https://go.dev/blog/error-handling-and-go). **2)** Check out some source codes in Go's net/http package, especially the `HandlerFunc` type and `Handler` interface, to fully understand the aforementioned section in the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK lots of questions there but I'll do my best to cover it all.

This defines a method `ServeHTTP` on the type `appHandler`, which means that `appHandler` is now a valid `net/http.Handler`. The type `appHandler` happens to be a function type, so yes - here you have a function value with methods you can call on it, separately from calling the function itself. This is already how `http.HandleFunc` works in the standard library, by the way - checking its source code might also help understand how this works.

When a handler is registered, `net/http` calls its `ServeHTTP` method to handle incoming requests. That method on our `appHandler` type is:

```
func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    }
}
```

So, there on the first line of the function, `ServeHTTP` calls the `appHandler` function - `fn appHandler` is our receiver, making `fn` a function value, which we can call:

```
fn(w, r)
```

This is utilized by converting our handler function to the `appHandler` type:

```
http.Handle("/view", appHandler(viewRecord))
```

This is no different really than the more common middleware pattern:

```
func middleware(fn func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        }
    }
}
```

This does the exact same thing, but using a closure and function parameter instead of a method and function receiver. This is utilized by calling our wrapper function:

```
http.Handle("/view", http.HandlerFunc(middleware(viewRecord)))
```

This uses our `middleware` function to wrap `viewRecord` and converts it to a `http.HandlerFunc` (which, as mentioned earlier, will in fact do the same thing `appHandler` was doing with the function type method).

Comment: OK, the last example helped a LOT for me. That `middleware` function is exactly how I would have done this, coming from a functional background. Meaning even as a beginner go programmer, writing what you call middleware that takes in the nonconforming function (viewRecord) and produces a conforming function is what I would have done. So what's interesting here is the conversion between this "style" and this "receiver" notation. I'll study this more, I still don't really feel like I have a grasp on this notation.

Comment: when you say "calls on it", do you mean "calls it"? Like, `func (fn somefunctype) y() ` means that `y()` can call `fn()`? As in `y() {fn()}`? This still seems different than `func (p person) talk()` where you then do `someperson.talk()`. The "calling order" is reversed.

Comment: how does, in your last example, the interface of Handler get met, since it doesn't have a function called `ServeHTTP`? Isn't `Handle` going to try to call `middleware(viewRecord).ServeHTTP`, but that does not exist?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - "calls on it" doesn't appear in my answer. `func (fn somefunctype) y()` means that the method `y`'s receiever is `fn`, so if `fn` is a function, it can call it, just like if it were a regular function parameter. Receivers *are* just regular function parameters, they just also apply syntax for calling the function as a method on a value of the receiver's type.

Comment: In my last example I wrapped in a `http.HandlerFunc` (which I typo'd as `HandleFunc` at first, sorry). As I noted at the end of the answer, `http.HandlerFunc` works just like your question's `appHandler` - it's a named function type which defines a `ServeHTTP` method: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc

Answer (score 5):

Any type can be a receiver. For instance:

```
type X int
```

Here, `X` is a new type, and you can create methods for it:

```
func (x X) method() {
  // Do something with x
}
```

In Go, functions are like any other type. So if you have a function type:

```
type F func()
```

Here, `F` is a new type, hence you can define methods for it:

```
func (x F) method() {
   x()
}
```

With the above declaration, now you can call `value.method()` if `value` is of type `F`.

```
a:=F(func() {fmt.Println("hey")})
a.method()
```

Here, `a` is a variable of type `F`. `F` has a method called `method`, so you can call `a.method`. When you call that, `a.method` calls `a`, which is a function.

Going back to you example, `appHandler` appears to be a function type:

```
type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
```

So any function with that signature can be used in place of a `appHandler`. Let's say you write such a function:

```
func myHandler(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
  // Handle request
}
```

You can pass this function whereever an `appHandler` is requested. However, you cannot pass if to where a `Handler` is required without writing a struct like this:

```
type myHandlerStruct struct{}

func (myHandlerStruct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   myHandler(w,r)
}
```

Instead of definine a new struct, you can define a method for the type `appHandler`:

```
func (a appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   a(w,r)
}
```

Now you can pass `appHandler` to where an `appHandler` required as well as where a `Handler` required. If it is called as a `Handler`, the `ServeHTTP` method will simply forward the call to the underlying function.

Comment: I get your point, but I think you didn't read the article OP linked. (I know, we're busy :) Your example is not wrong by *itself*, but it can be confusing because it's not very related to the link OP is talking about.